# Trying to get an if statement to check how long since or until a date

Tags: c#, datetime

This if statement does not trigger and just goes onto other if statements below, I need it to check that there has been less than 48 hours since the order was placed and less than 48 hours until the delivery date/time (The dates are created when the order is created)

```
  if (order.COrderDate > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-48) && DateTime.Now.AddHours(-48) >  order.CDeliveryDate)
            {
                refund.transactionId = order.transactionId;
                refund.UserEmail = order.CEmail;
                decimal refundtot = order.CTotal;


                refundtot = (75 / 100) * refundtot;
                refund.RefundTotal = refundtot;

                storeDB.Refunds.Add(refund);
                await storeDB.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
```

Comment: `TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - otherDate; if (ts.TotalHours > 48) { }`

Comment: You added negative 48 both times, just remove the negative sign in the second `AddHours`.

Comment: @juharr No, that is not all. If you do that it takes all delivery dates in the past too.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It says _less than 48 hours until the delivery date/time_, so if it's already delivered that's a negative number which is less than 48.  Really you should ask if the OP needs to additionally check if the delivery has already occurred since there is no context here to say that matters.

Comment: @juharr It can be my misunderstanding of the English language, but as far as I know, *until* always denotes something in the future.

Comment: @PatrickHofman hey can you do me a favor and upvote this post. otherwise I'm going to get banned, thanks

Comment: It is better not to ask such things. We vote if we think the post deserves it. Often asking for upvotes only brings downvotes.

Comment: could you tell me, w

Comment: @PatrickHofman well could you tell me why this post deserved to be downvoted?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Honestly based on the fact that this seems to be refund logic it would make more since for it to be "The deliver date is at least 48 hours in the future" meaning that the delivery isn't eminent.  Ultimately the OP has to be specific if we are to determine exactly what is needed.

Comment: @mmmmmkeyisstuckmmmmmmmmmm Down votes are suppose to mean that the question does not show research effort, is unclear, or not useful.  I did not personally down vote, but I could see arguments made for all 3 cases.

Comment: @mmmmmkeyisstuckmmmmmmmmmm I didn't vote, so I can't say why that person downvoted. And I am not doing guessing games.

Comment: @PatrickHofman ok but for your answer below wont DateTime.Now.AddHours(48) never be true

Comment: @PatrickHofman NVM my mistake

Comment: @mmmmmkeyisstuckmmmmmmmmmm Do you need more help or was my answer sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

> less than 48 hours until the delivery date/time

So that time should be in the future. `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-48)` is about the past.

A better check would be:

```
order.CDeliveryDate < DateTime.Now.AddHours(48)
```

But that is not all, since you also have to check the lower bound (or you will end up with delivery dates in the past):

```
order.CDeliveryDate > DateTime.Now && order.CDeliveryDate < DateTime.Now.AddHours(48)
```